# Ionic 3 Cordova ajax calls fail on Windows 10 (UWP)

Tags: ajax, cordova, uwp, ionic3, visual-studio-cordova

I just cannot get my ajax calls to work on an Ionic 3 Cordova application built for a Windows 10 UWP. They can access localhost, but not any outside connections.

The application works fine on both Android and iOS.

I am trying to test this locally on my dev machine. I use a certificate (bought) to sign the application, install this certificate, build the application for Windows, and am able to open up the built `CordovaApp.Windows10_1.0.1.1_x86.appxupload`, and then double click the embedded `CordovaApp.Windows10_1.0.1.1_x86.appx` file to install, which completes successfully. The install indicates the app need internet access.

In the `config.xml`, I have the following tags, as suggested elsewhere...

```
 <allow-navigation href="*" />
 <access origin="*" />
```

However, when I run, the http.get call just returns `0` with no other information. I can run in Visual Studio, and look at the returned error object, and get no further info, apart from this `0` return.

I have run fiddler, enabled the https decryption as explained [here](https://www.fiddlerbook.com/fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp), but all I see in the response header is

```
HTTP/1.0 200 Connection Established
FiddlerGateway: Direct
StartTime: 13:44:21.686
Connection: close
```

The result in the main view actually shows `200`, so I don't think this is showing me anything real.

What could I be missing?

Should I be able to use external ajax on a Windows 10 machine, when I have sideloaded the application as here? I haven't tried from the store yet, as I don't want to upload until I know it works.

### Update 1

If I run the application on the same machine, just using Ionic serve (so it just runs in the browser rather than hosted in the UWP), the ajax calls also work fine.

### Update 2

I have now created a Cordova application using the Visual Studio template, so taking all other frameworks out of the equation.

I used vanilla JavaScript to do my rest call...

```
 document.addEventListener('deviceready', callUrl, false);

 function callUrl() {
  
  console.log('callUrl'); 
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', 'https://myserveraddress.com/myapp/testroute');
  xhr.send(null);

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    var DONE = 4; // readyState 4 means the request is done.
    var OK = 200; // status 200 is a successful return.
    if (xhr.readyState === DONE) {
      if (xhr.status === OK)
        console.log(xhr.responseText); 
    } else {
      console.log('Error: ' + xhr.status); 
    }
  }
 };
```

I run this in the debugger, and even here I get an error (status code of 0).

Another thing I noticed when I open up the build package and look at the `cordova_plugins.js` file..

My Ionic app has the following...

```
cordova.define('cordova/plugin_list', function(require, exports, module) {
    module.exports = [
        {
            "id": "cordova-plugin-console.logger",
            "file": "plugins/cordova-plugin-console/www/logger.js",
            "pluginId": "cordova-plugin-console",
            "clobbers": [
                "cordova.logger"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "cordova-plugin-console.console",
            "file": "plugins/cordova-plugin-console/www/console-via-logger.js",
            "pluginId": "cordova-plugin-console",
            "clobbers": [
                "console"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "cordova-plugin-device.device",
            "file": "plugins/cordova-plugin-device/www/device.js",
            "pluginId": "cordova-plugin-device",
            "clobbers": [
                "device"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "cordova-plugin-device.DeviceProxy",
            "file": "plugins/cordova-plugin-device/src/windows/DeviceProxy.js",
            "pluginId": "cordova-plugin-device",
            "merges": [
                ""
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "cordova-plugin-splashscreen.SplashScreen",
            "file": "plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/www/splashscreen.js",
            "pluginId": "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
            "clobbers": [
                "navigator.splashscreen"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "cordova-plugin-splashscreen.SplashScreenProxy",
            "file": "plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/www/windows/SplashScreenProxy.js",
            "pluginId": "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
            "runs": true
        },
        {
            "id": "cordova-plugin-statusbar.statusbar",
            "file": "plugins/cordova-plugin-statusbar/www/statusbar.js",
            "pluginId": "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
            "clobbers": [
                "window.StatusBar"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "cordova-plugin-statusbar.StatusBarProxy",
            "file": "plugins/cordova-plugin-statusbar/src/windows/StatusBarProxy.js",
            "pluginId": "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
            "runs": true
        },
        {
            "id": "ionic-plugin-keyboard.KeyboardProxy",
            "file": "plugins/ionic-plugin-keyboard/src/windows/KeyboardProxy.js",
            "pluginId": "ionic-plugin-keyboard",
            "clobbers": [
                "cordova.plugins.Keyboard"
            ],
            "runs": true
        }
    ];
    module.exports.metadata = 
    // TOP OF METADATA
    {
        "cordova-plugin-console": "1.0.5",
        "cordova-plugin-device": "1.1.4",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "4.0.3",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.2.2",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.1",
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "2.2.1"
    };
    // BOTTOM OF METADATA
    });
```

Now, I notice every plugin in the `module.exports.metadata` also has an entry in the `module.exports` *except* for `cordova-plugin-whitelist`!

If I open the same file for the Corvoda application created in VS, I see the following...

```
cordova.define('cordova/plugin_list', function(require, exports, module) {
    module.exports = [];
    module.exports.metadata = 
    // TOP OF METADATA
    {
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.2.2"
    };
    // BOTTOM OF METADATA
    });
```

So this has nothing else for the whitelist plugin as well

Could there be something missing here? Could this white-list plugin not be installed correctly?

Comment: After a long time, I did what I should have long before, and tested the application on another network, and, it worked fine. From my home, or if the device is tethered to the cell network, no problems. Only problems are on the work network. Since this is a bit different, I've created a separate [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46480462/how-to-troubleshoot-local-windows-uwp-cordova-networking-issues) for this "new" problem, which may be more instrafructure related as opposed to app

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation where my ajax calls worked fine in TEST, but when I moved to PROD, they would fail.

The answer was finally tracked down as a missing intermediary certificate on the server I was trying to access.  TEST had the cert, PROD did not.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for that. not sure which certificate you mean here? I am sure my problem is on the local client machine as the request never seems to get to the server (I don't even see it in Wireshark). My problem now looks like it may be the specific network I am testing on, so have added this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46480462/how-to-troubleshoot-local-windows-uwp-cordova-networking-issues) for the problem.

Comment: My ajax was trying to access https://www.someserver.net and the machine running someserver.net had an ssl cert, but a certificate prior in the certificate chain of the ssl cert was missing.  Specifically, it was a NetScaler instance that was missing the intermediary certificate.

Comment: If I remember correctly, when we tried Wireshark, the traffic never made it to someserver.net, but stopped at the NetScaler instance.