# How to get more error information from an Angular http ajax call

Tags: ajax, angular, cordova, ionic2

I have been trying to diagnose a [http problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45809788/ionic-3-cordova-ajax-calls-fail-on-windows-10-uwp) for what seems forever now.

I thought I would go back to a very simple sample Ionic (Angular) application I can use to test, where I have the following test code...

```
public onClick() : void {  
  this.http.get(this.url).subscribe(res => {
   this.result = res.statusText;
   console.log(res);
 }, error => {
   this.result = `failed  ${error.statusText}`;
   console.log(error);
 });
```

}

The url just comes from an input.

If I force an error, (eg put an incorrect url), I notice the error from the observable always has a status os 0, and no statusText. In the browser network tab, I see the 404 as expected...

```
   identityx    404 xhr polyfills.js:3  160 B   10 ms
```

Is there a way to get better error information back from the http call, rather than just 0 all the time (and no status text)? I've look through the error object, but can't see anything.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you want to see? If you need the status code, it's `error.status`

Comment: That's the thing, the status code is always **0**. So I just ran with an invalid url, and I have the following in the response object.. `headers
:
Headers {_headers: Map(0), _normalizedNames: Map(0)}
ok
:
false
status
:
0
statusText
:
""
type
:
3
url
:
null
_body
:
ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: "error", …}
__proto__
:
Body`

Comment: Most likely caused by CORS

Comment: I have had endless trouble with CORS (the very term gives me a headache), but I thought I had this all solved, at least with my backend service that should allow CORS.. so it seems that even if you point to a service that returns nothing (as the end point does not exist), you don't get any details (eg the 404)