# Cordova : How to diagnose ajax not working for UWP (windows store) application

Tags: ajax, cordova, http, uwp

I have a simple Cordova application, where when built, and running as a Windows UWP application, has ajax calls are somehow being blocked my work network.

I have asked this many times before, but thought would try to reword, as have never got any solutions.

The application ajax calls work fine on my home machine, or whats seems to be most other networks. When it works, I can see all the output in [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)

When on my work machine, connected to our work Network, I see absolutely nothing in Wireshark. If I point to a server running on localhost, the app **does work** (but I see nothing in Wireshark, but perhaps this is because it is localhost)

If I run the app outside of the **UWP container**, ie I just run on the same machine, on the same network, but via the desktop browser (as you do for Cordova to debugging), it also works fine.

So it appears to be blocked before it even gets to the Network, as we see nothing in Wireshark at all, so this rules out host not reachable, CORS etc as it hasn't even been sent to the server.

I can run this in debug via Visual Studio, and I run the following test code...

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', callUrl, false);

function callUrl() {

  console.log('callUrl'); 
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    var DONE = 4; // readyState 4 means the request is done.
    var OK = 200; // status 200 is a successful return.
    console.log(xhr.readyState);
    if (xhr.readyState === DONE) {
      if (xhr.status === OK)
        console.log(xhr.responseText); // 'This is the returned text.'
    } else {
      console.log('Error: ' + xhr.status); // An error occurred during the request.
    }
  }

  xhr.open('GET', 'https://httpbin.org/get');
  xhr.send(null);
```

};

`onreadystatechange`is called twice, with `xhr.readyState` first 2 and then 4.
`status` is always 0.

How can I diagnose what is blocking this?? I have absolutely no idea. This is something low level, but how to see what? I have also looked through Windows Event logs, but can find nothing.

The Ajax call just returns **0** with a blank description. Our Network administrator just says there is something wrong with my app (I have tried multiple Cordova apps, including just basic test apps)

Thanks in advance for any help.

**[EDIT1]**

In response to the comment from @Xavier, all I have in my `AppxManifest.xml` (that I extracted from my built `.appxupload` file) is

```
<Capabilities> 
  <Capability Name="internetClient" /> 
</Capabilities>
```

There is some documentation on the capabilities [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/win8/#understanding-remote-mode-vs-local-mode), where we have the following (right at the bottom of the page)..

```
    The following capabilities are unavailable when deploying your Remote Mode application to the Windows Store:

    Enterprise Authentication (enterpriseAuthentication)
    Shared User Certificates (sharedUserCertificates)
    Documents Library (documentsLibrary)
    Music Library (musicLibrary)
    Pictures Library (picturesLibrary)
    Videos Library (videosLibrary)
    Removable Storage (removableStorage)
    Internet client/server (internetClientServer) - note that internetClient is still permitted
    Private network client/server (privateNetworkClientServer)
```

I am not sure were we even set these in Visual Studio (config.xml), but also the above seems to be saying some of these can't be used?

Should the `internetClient` be enough (I only want to call out to a server as a client, not act as a server).

Also, this seems to be enough to work on most Networks except for my Work..

**[EDIT2]**

In response to the reply on the CSP...

There is a discussion on this [here](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/cordova-security-whitlists). The test Cordova app I created in Visual Studio does have this :

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

Surprisingly, I don't see this in my Ionic index.html, but perhaps this is because it is using the white list plugin?

My Ionic application has the following in the config.xml

```
  <access origin="*" />
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
  <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
  <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
  <allow-navigation href="http://localhost:8080/*" />
  ....
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.1" />
```

It would be great if the ajax even had some error saying it was something to do with CSP if that is what it is, but we just get nothing.

Once again, it is weird that the problem only occurs on my work network (either on cable or our WIFI). If I run the exact machine (e.g. a Surface tablet)over another connection (e.g. tether it to my phones cell), then all works as expected. So it must be some setting to do with the network (or firewall maybe), which also I find strange as surely I would at least then see something in Wireshark.

Would be great to be able to "debug into" the ajax call, and see where it is failing.

**[EDIT 3]**

After reading one of the comments, I used fiddler to see if I could see anything, which I do...

[image]

It even reports 200 (which is not correct), my request still fails.

Comment: Have you enabled the networks relevant capabilities in 'Package.appxmanifest'? E.g, `Private Networks(client & server)`, `Internet(Client)`, `Internet(Client & Server)`, `Enterprise Authentication`

Comment: Hmm, the only thing I see in the AppxManifest.xml is  `<Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
  </Capabilities>` There is some doco on the other modes (https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/win8/#understanding-remote-mode-vs-local-mode)[here]. Is this saying we can't use them?

Comment: I'll add notes to the question (not enough room here)

Comment: If so, this might be related to CSP([Content Security Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy)) issue, you could try to edit the HTML META tag like this `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com https://httpbin.org 'unsafe-eval' ; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">`

Comment: Thanks for that. I've added some info as [EDIT2]

Comment: I'm having the same issue here. a solution is very much welcome. my capablilities are the same, cors are set to very generous. it was working on one machine but with no apparent reason. we're digging in the dark, too.

Comment: Update: it's working now, but we cannot explain why. we startet our cordova app from the store, tried a post request (did work) and kept the app running. then we installed fiddler to see network requests and as soon as we did this, it was working. we reversed our steps - stopped fiddler, reinstalled the app from store and it is still working. what is going on?

Comment: @P. Stresow - I've added my fiddler output to the question. I didn't have any luck like you, even when running fiddler my request still fails.

Comment: @peterc did you find a solution? According to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations, you need to request the privateNetworkClientServer capability.

Comment: @Dominic - No I hadn't but OMG, that fixed it!!! prev read.. `internetClient` I need? It says `The internetClient capability indicates that apps can receive incoming data from the Internet`. And also `privateNetworkClientServer .. On Windows, this capability does not provide access to the Internet.Also at https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/windows/index.html it lists in the section `privateNetworkClientServer` in `The following capabilities are unavailable`! But I added it, and it worked !If you add your comment as a solution, I'll give it a million votes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations), you need to request the `privateNetworkClientServer` capability in order to communicate with a local network.

Note that this capability only works if you app is configured for [local mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/tools-for-cordova/security/best-practices?view=toolsforcordova-2017#use-local-mode-for-windows-10) (your app will be rejected from the store if using this capability in remote mode).

To enable local mode, you need to set `<preference name="WindowsDefaultUriPrefix" value="ms-appx://" />` in your cordova config.xml.

Note that local mode might lead to other issues, as you cannot use e.g. inline scripts in local mode (CSP violation)

Comment: This was the fix for me! Thankyou! Also for the explanation on how to set this "local mode".  I added the `<preference name="WindowsDefaultUriPrefix" value="ms-appx://" />` (with great fear), however everything on my app (Ionic 3) still appear to work (at least testing on my desktop)

Comment: When testing, I was using Visual studio to add this capacity. So it is now part of the build, to add this capacity, I used [this plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-windows-capability-private-network). Seemed to work for me

Comment: Damn, finally got to submit after doing this (spent another month on trying to find out how to renew an expired certificate), and now I get the following from the store submission.. `The app manifest test detected the following errors:
o The Application cannot include an ApplicationContentUriRule with 'all' or 'allowForWebOnly' WindowsRuntimeAccess while any of the following capabilities are enabled: enterpriseAuthentication, sharedUserCertificates, musicLibrary, picturesLibrary, videosLibrary, removableStorage, documentLibrary, internetClientServer, privateNetworkClientServer`.

Comment: I did double check that I have the `<preference name="WindowsDefaultUriPrefix" value="ms-appx://" />` in the config.xml. The were really no help when I asked what is wrong, I was just pointed towards the forums. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: I have posted a new question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52960298/why-does-ionic-cordova-build-for-windows-uwp-add-content-uri-to-appxmanifest).

Comment: And also and also [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/6d7a5c6b-8416-4da5-982c-bd77cafad30d/store-certification-failure-for-cordova-uwp-app-the-application-cannot-include-an?forum=wpsubmit).

Comment: Looks like my other issue was due to <allow-navigation href="http://localhost:8080/*" /> being in my config.xml (no idea how or why this was here). Removing it, and the above works and accepted by the store