# Why does Ionic/Cordova build for Windows UWP add Content URI to appxmanifest?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I have an Ionic(3) Cordova application, where I want to include a Windows UWP version. On iOS and Android I have no problems, but UWP I just cannot get my ajax to work and be store compliant. My issue is with my ajax calls being blocked on corporate networks as outlined [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/6d7a5c6b-8416-4da5-982c-bd77cafad30d/store-certification-failure-for-cordova-uwp-app-the-application-cannot-include-an?forum=wpsubmit)

So, the issue was I needed to add `privateNetworkClientServer`, which when testing locally, fixed the blocking issue. Also, as explained in the link, I have attempted to add the "local mode".

The store now rejects it with

```
Error Found: The app manifest test detected the following errors:
    o    The Application cannot include an ApplicationContentUriRule with 'all' or 'allowForWebOnly' WindowsRuntimeAccess while any of the following capabilities are enabled: enterpriseAuthentication, sharedUserCertificates, musicLibrary, picturesLibrary, videosLibrary, removableStorage, documentLibrary, internetClientServer, privateNetworkClientServer.
```

So, now I am trying to remove the

```
<uap:ApplicationContentUriRules>
            <uap:Rule Match="http://localhost:8080/*" Type="include" WindowsRuntimeAccess="all" />
 </uap:ApplicationContentUriRules>
```

from the appmanifest, but when I do the Ionic/Cordova build, it keeps adding it back.

It seems there is something wrong with everything I do, all I want to do is run ajax calls across a network (seems like a pretty common case to me)

Anyway, does anyone have any ideas on this latest problem, Ie the

```
 <uap:Rule Match="http://localhost:8080/*" Type="include" 
     WindowsRuntimeAccess="all" />
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You had used the capability privateNetworkClientServer and it seems network-related restrictions .For network-related restrictions must be worked around by either using an API that doesn't use capability checks or by brokering communication via standard internet communication channels, such as XMLHttpRequest or Web Sockets. Could you change your configuration and try again according to this restriction?Derive from this [https://github.com/apache/cordova-windows/blob/master/cordova-windows10.md#remote-access-and-capabilities]

Comment: @Diasy - thanks again for the input. I am afraid I am not quite sure what they are alluding to in the statement "brokering communication via standard internet communication channels, such as XMLHttpRequest or Web Sockets". My app just does simple ajax requests to a REST service. This service can be on premise for our clients, most (if not all) will have the service (asp.net WebAPI) on the corporate network. When I was testing my app on my work corporate network, it worked fine on Android and iOS, but not the UWP until I enabled the privateNetworkClientServer. Nothing else I tried worked.

Comment: Can you post your config.xml and your AppxManifest.xml? My appxmanifest.xml doesn't seem to have this ApplicationContentUriRules entry.

Comment: @Dominic - thanks for the reply. Your comment make me reexamine my the `config.xml` I noticed I have the entry `<allow-navigation href="http://localhost:8080/*" />`, and this is what is adding it to the AppxManifest. I am not sure why this is here, or if I added it. I created a new blank Ionic app, and it does NOT have it!. This could be my problem! Resubmitting a new build to the store now . Lets see if this is it.

Comment: I don't think I have this entry... good luck! :-)

Comment: With `<allow-navigation href="http://localhost:8080/*" />` removed, it is now passed store certification. I really don't know how or why that was there. What a journey that was! Thankyou all for your help.